# Android studio: No data showing up at my simple Registration android app powered by SQLite database

Tags: java, android, database, android-sqlite

I have a simple Android app that takes in information from users input then store it in a database then it creates an entry so that when a user click on it, they can see the stored information from that entry and be able to edit and update any information from it. The code is mainly derived from stevdza-san SQLite tutorial about databases https://github.com/stevdza-san/SQLite_Android-Complete_Tutorial/tree/master/app/src/main/java/com/jovanovic/stefan/sqlitetutorial

As I tried to modify the code to meet my desired result, when I test it, it says it successfully added the data from the database but when I click the entry, an error shows up saying No data, and indeed no data can be shown.

(https://i.stack.imgur.com/XganH.png)

But you can see on that image the database, the information was successfully stored, but for some reason there is something in the code that prevents me from accessing that data. Will you guys send suggestions what kind of changes to make to fix this problem of 'No data' shwoing on an entry.
(I already ensure that every Id from the Xml layout that is referrenced in the java files are correct, and there is no error showing up in the IDE, which means that there is some logic in the code are incorrect or missing).

**AddActivity.java**

```java
package com.example.seashore_registration;

import...

public class AddActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    EditText (tldr. all are correctly named and referenced);
    Button add_button;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_add);

        last_name = findViewById(R.id.last_name);
        first_name = findViewById(R.id.first_name);
        middle_name = findViewById(R.id.middle_name);
        res_address = findViewById(R.id.res_address);
        years_residency = findViewById(R.id.years_residency);
        ownership = findViewById(R.id.ownership);
        sex = findViewById(R.id.sex);
        citizenship = findViewById(R.id.citizenship);
        tinNumber = findViewById(R.id.tinNumber);
        cellphone = findViewById(R.id.cellphone);
        passport_num = findViewById(R.id.passport_num);
        place_issue = findViewById(R.id.place_issue);
        date_issue = findViewById(R.id.date_issue);
        email = findViewById(R.id.email);
        beneficiary = findViewById(R.id.beneficiary);
        dependents = findViewById(R.id.dependents);
        company_name = findViewById(R.id.company_name);
        office_num = findViewById(R.id.office_num);
        company_address = findViewById(R.id.company_address);
        company_email = findViewById(R.id.company_email);
        employment_status = findViewById(R.id.employment_status);

        add_button = findViewById(R.id.add_button);
        add_button.setOnClickListener(view -> {
            MyDatabaseHelper myDB = new MyDatabaseHelper(AddActivity.this);
            myDB.addBook(last_name.getText().toString().trim(),
                    first_name.getText().toString().trim(),
                    middle_name.getText().toString().trim(),
                    res_address.getText().toString().trim(),
                    Integer.valueOf(years_residency.getText().toString().trim()),
                    ownership.getText().toString().trim(),
                    sex.getText().toString().trim(),
                    citizenship.getText().toString().trim(),
                    Integer.valueOf(tinNumber.getText().toString().trim()),
                    Integer.valueOf(cellphone.getText().toString().trim()),
                    Integer.valueOf(passport_num.getText().toString().trim()),
                    place_issue.getText().toString().trim(),
                    date_issue.getText().toString().trim(),
                    email.getText().toString().trim(),
                    beneficiary.getText().toString().trim(),
                    dependents.getText().toString().trim(),
                    company_name.getText().toString().trim(),
                    Integer.valueOf(office_num.getText().toString().trim()),
                    company_address.getText().toString().trim(),
                    company_email.getText().toString().trim(),
                    employment_status.getText().toString().trim());

        });
    }
}
```

**CustomAdapter.java**

```java
package com.example.seashore_registration;

import ...

public class CustomAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<CustomAdapter.MyViewHolder> {

    private Context context;
    private Activity activity;
    private ArrayList (tldr. all are correctly named and referenced);

    CustomAdapter(Activity activity, Context context, ArrayList _id,
                  ArrayList last_name,
                  ArrayList first_name,
                  ArrayList middle_name,
                  ArrayList res_address,
                  ArrayList years_residency,
                  ArrayList _ownership,
                  ArrayList _sex,
                  ArrayList _citizenship,
                  ArrayList _tinNumber,
                  ArrayList _cellphone,
                  ArrayList passport_num,
                  ArrayList place_issue,
                  ArrayList date_issue,
                  ArrayList _email,
                  ArrayList _beneficiary,
                  ArrayList _dependents,
                  ArrayList company_name,
                  ArrayList office_num,
                  ArrayList company_address,
                  ArrayList company_email,
                  ArrayList employment_status) {
        this.activity = activity;
        this.context = context;
        this._id = _id;
        this.last_name = last_name;
        this.first_name = first_name;
        this.middle_name = middle_name;
        this.res_address = res_address;
        this.years_residency = years_residency;
        this._ownership = _ownership;
        this._sex = _sex;
        this._citizenship = _citizenship;
        this._tinNumber = _tinNumber;
        this._cellphone = _cellphone;
        this.passport_num = passport_num;
        this.place_issue = place_issue;
        this.date_issue = date_issue;
        this._email = _email;
        this._beneficiary = _beneficiary;
        this._dependents = _dependents;
        this.company_name = company_name;
        this.office_num = office_num;
        this.company_address = company_address;
        this.company_email = company_email;
        this.employment_status = employment_status;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.my_row, parent, false);
        return new MyViewHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull final MyViewHolder holder, @SuppressLint("RecyclerView") final int position) {
        holder.book_id_txt.setText(String.valueOf(_id.get(position)));
        holder.last_name_txt.setText(String.valueOf(last_name.get(position)));
        holder.first_name_txt.setText(String.valueOf(last_name.get(position)));
        holder.cellphone_txt.setText(String.valueOf(_cellphone.get(position)));


        //Recyclerview onClickListener
        holder.mainLayout.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(context, UpdateActivity.class);
                intent.putExtra("id", String.valueOf(_id.get(position)));
                intent.putExtra("last_name", String.valueOf(last_name.get(position)));
                intent.putExtra("first_name", String.valueOf(first_name.get(position)));
                intent.putExtra("cellphone", String.valueOf(_cellphone.get(position)));

                activity.startActivityForResult(intent, 1);
            }
        });

    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return _id.size();
    }

    class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        TextView book_id_txt, last_name_txt, first_name_txt, cellphone_txt;
        LinearLayout mainLayout;

        MyViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            book_id_txt = itemView.findViewById(R.id.book_id_txt);
            last_name_txt = itemView.findViewById(R.id.last_name_txt);
            first_name_txt = itemView.findViewById(R.id.first_name_txt);
            cellphone_txt = itemView.findViewById(R.id.cellhpone_number_txt);
            mainLayout = itemView.findViewById(R.id.mainLayout);
            //Animate Recyclerview
            Animation translate_anim = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(context, R.anim.translate_anim);
            mainLayout.setAnimation(translate_anim);
        }

    }

}
```

**MainActivity.java**

```java
package com.example.seashore_registration;

import ...

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    RecyclerView recyclerView;
    FloatingActionButton add_button;
    ImageView empty_imageview;
    TextView no_data;

    MyDatabaseHelper myDB;
    ArrayList<String> (tldr. all are correctly named and referenced);

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.recyclerView);
        add_button = findViewById(R.id.add_button);
        empty_imageview = findViewById(R.id.empty_imageview);
        no_data = findViewById(R.id.no_data);
        add_button.setOnClickListener(view -> {
            Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, AddActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        });

        myDB = new MyDatabaseHelper(MainActivity.this);
        _id = new ArrayList<>();
        last_name = new ArrayList<>();
        first_name = new ArrayList<>();
        middle_name = new ArrayList<>();
        res_address = new ArrayList<>();
        years_residency = new ArrayList<>();
        _ownership = new ArrayList<>();
        _sex = new ArrayList<>();
        _citizenship = new ArrayList<>();
        _tinNumber = new ArrayList<>();
        cellphone_number = new ArrayList<>();
        passport_num = new ArrayList<>();
        place_issue = new ArrayList<>();
        date_issue = new ArrayList<>();
        _email = new ArrayList<>();
        _beneficiary = new ArrayList<>();
        _dependents = new ArrayList<>();
        company_name = new ArrayList<>();
        office_num = new ArrayList<>();
        company_address = new ArrayList<>();
        company_email = new ArrayList<>();
        employment_status = new ArrayList<>();

        storeDataInArrays();

        customAdapter = new CustomAdapter(MainActivity.this, this, _id, last_name, first_name, middle_name,res_address, years_residency, _ownership, _sex, _citizenship, _tinNumber, cellphone_number,passport_num, place_issue, date_issue, _email, _beneficiary, _dependents, company_name,office_num, company_address,company_email, employment_status);
        recyclerView.setAdapter(customAdapter);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(MainActivity.this));

    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, @Nullable Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if (requestCode == 1) {
            recreate();
        }
    }

    void storeDataInArrays() {
        Cursor cursor = myDB.readAllData();
        if (cursor.getCount() == 0) {
            empty_imageview.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            no_data.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        } else {
            while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
                _id.add(cursor.getString(0));
                last_name.add(cursor.getString(1));
                first_name.add(cursor.getString(2));
                middle_name.add(cursor.getString(3));
                res_address.add(cursor.getString(4));
                years_residency.add(cursor.getString(5));
                _ownership.add(cursor.getString(6));
                _sex.add(cursor.getString(7));
                _citizenship.add(cursor.getString(8));
                _tinNumber.add(cursor.getString(9));
                cellphone_number.add(cursor.getString(10));
                passport_num.add(cursor.getString(11));
                place_issue.add(cursor.getString(12));
                date_issue.add(cursor.getString(13));
                _email.add(cursor.getString(14));
                _beneficiary.add(cursor.getString(15));
                _dependents.add(cursor.getString(16));
                company_name.add(cursor.getString(17));
                office_num.add(cursor.getString(18));
                company_address.add(cursor.getString(19));
                company_email.add(cursor.getString(20));
                employment_status.add(cursor.getString(21));
            }
            empty_imageview.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            no_data.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.my_menu, menu);
        return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        if (item.getItemId() == R.id.delete_all) {
            confirmDialog();
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    void confirmDialog() {
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        builder.setTitle("Delete All?");
        builder.setMessage("Are you sure you want to delete all Data?");
        builder.setPositiveButton("Yes", (dialogInterface, i) -> {
            MyDatabaseHelper myDB = new MyDatabaseHelper(MainActivity.this);
            myDB.deleteAllData();
            //Refresh Activity
            Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
            finish();
        }).setNegativeButton("No", (dialogInterface, i) -> {

        });
        builder.create().show();
    }
}
```

**MyDatabaseHelper.java**

````java
package com.example.seashore_registration;

import ...

class MyDatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    private Context context;
    private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "BookLibrary.db";
    private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;

    private static final String TABLE_NAME = "my_library";
    private static final String COLUMN_ID = "_id";
    private static final String COLUMN_LAST_NA = "last_name";
    private static final String COLUMN_FIRST_NA = "first_name";
    private static final String COLUMN_MIDDLE_NA = "middle_name";
    private static final String COLUMN_RES_ADD = "res_address";
    private static final String COLUMN_YEARS_RESIDENT = "years_residency";
    private static final String COLUMN_OWNER = "_ownership";
    private static final String COLUMN_GENDER = "_sex";
    private static final String COLUMN_CITIZEN = "_citizenship";
    private static final String COLUMN_TIN = "_tinNumber";
    private static final String COLUMN_CP = "_cellphone";
    private static final String COLUMN_PASSPORT_N = "passport_num";
    private static final String COLUMN_PLACE_ISSUED = "place_issue";
    private static final String COLUMN_DATE_ISSUED = "date_issue";
    private static final String COLUMN_EMAIL_ADD = "_email";
    private static final String COLUMN_BENEFIT = "_beneficiary";
    private static final String COLUMN_DEPENDENT = "_dependents";
    private static final String COLUMN_COMPANY_N = "company_name";
    private static final String COLUMN_OFFICE_NUMBER = "office_num";
    private static final String COLUMN_COMPANY_ADD = "company_address";
    private static final String COLUMN_COMPANY_EM = "company_email";
    private static final String COLUMN_EMPLOYMENT_STAT = "employment_status";


    MyDatabaseHelper(@Nullable Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
        this.context = context;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        String query = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_NAME +
                " (" + COLUMN_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " +
                COLUMN_LAST_NA + " TEXT, " +
                COLUMN_FIRST_NA + " TEXT, " +
                COLUMN_MIDDLE_NA + " TEXT, " +
                COLUMN_RES_ADD + " TEXT, " +
                COLUMN_YEARS_RESIDENT + " INTEGER, " +
                COLUMN_OWNER + " TEXT, " +
                COLUMN_GENDER + " TEXT, " +
                COLUMN_CITIZEN + " TEXT, " +
                COLUMN_TIN + " INTEGER, " +
                COLUMN_CP + " INTEGER, " +
                COLUMN_PASSPORT_N + " INTEGER, " +
                COLUMN_PLACE_ISSUED + " TEXT, " +
                COLUMN_DATE_ISSUED + " TEXT, " +
                COLUMN_EMAIL_ADD + " TEXT, " +
                COLUMN_BENEFIT + " TEXT, " +
                COLUMN_DEPENDENT + " TEXT, " +
                COLUMN_COMPANY_N + " TEXT, " +
                COLUMN_OFFICE_NUMBER + " INTEGER, " +
                COLUMN_COMPANY_ADD + " TEXT, " +
                COLUMN_COMPANY_EM + " TEXT, " +
                COLUMN_EMPLOYMENT_STAT + " TEXT);";
        db.execSQL(query);
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int i, int i1) {
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_NAME);
        onCreate(db);
    }

    void addBook(tldr. all are correctly named and referenced) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();

        cv.put(COLUMN_LAST_NA, last_name);
        cv.put(COLUMN_FIRST_NA, first_name);
        cv.put(COLUMN_MIDDLE_NA, middle_name);
        cv.put(COLUMN_RES_ADD, res_address);
        cv.put(COLUMN_YEARS_RESIDENT, years_residency);
       ..................... (tldr. all are correctly named and referenced);

        long result = db.insert(TABLE_NAME, null, cv);
        if (result == -1) {
            Toast.makeText(context, "Failed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(context, "Added Successfully!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }

    Cursor readAllData() {
        String query = "SELECT * FROM " + TABLE_NAME;
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();

        Cursor cursor = null;
        if (db != null) {
            cursor = db.rawQuery(query, null);
        }
        return cursor;
    }

    void updateData(tldr. all are correctly named and referenced) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
        cv.put(COLUMN_LAST_NA, last_name);
        cv.put(COLUMN_FIRST_NA, first_name);
        cv.put(COLUMN_MIDDLE_NA, middle_name);
        cv.put(COLUMN_RES_ADD, res_address);
        cv.put(COLUMN_YEARS_RESIDENT, years_residency); .....
       .......................... (tldr. all are correctly named and referenced);

        long result = db.update(TABLE_NAME, cv, "_id=?", new String[]{row_id});
        if (result == -1) {
            Toast.makeText(context, "Failed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(context, "Updated Successfully!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

    }

    void deleteOneRow(String row_id) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        long result = db.delete(TABLE_NAME, "_id=?", new String[]{row_id});
        if (result == -1) {
            Toast.makeText(context, "Failed to Delete.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(context, "Successfully Deleted.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }

    void deleteAllData() {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        db.execSQL("DELETE FROM " + TABLE_NAME);
    }

}

**UpdateActivity.java**

```java
package com.example.seashore_registration;

import ...

public class UpdateActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    EditText (tldr. all are correctly named and referenced);

    String (tldr. all are correctly named and referenced);

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_update);

        last_name = findViewById(R.id.last_name2);
        first_name = findViewById(R.id.first_name2);
        middle_name = findViewById(R.id.middle_name2);
        res_address = findViewById(R.id.res_address2);
        years_residency = findViewById(R.id.years_residency2);
        ownership = findViewById(R.id.ownership2);
        sex = findViewById(R.id.sex2);
        citizenship = findViewById(R.id.citizenship2);
        tinNumber = findViewById(R.id.tinNumber2);
        cellphone = findViewById(R.id.cellphone2);
        passport_num = findViewById(R.id.passport_num2);
        place_issue = findViewById(R.id.place_issue2);
        date_issue = findViewById(R.id.date_issue2);
        email = findViewById(R.id.email2);
        beneficiary = findViewById(R.id.beneficiary2);
        dependents = findViewById(R.id.dependents2);
        company_name = findViewById(R.id.company_name2);
        office_num = findViewById(R.id.office_num2);
        company_address = findViewById(R.id.company_address2);
        company_email = findViewById(R.id.company_email2);
        employment_status = findViewById(R.id.employment_status2);

        update_button = findViewById(R.id.update_button);
        delete_button = findViewById(R.id.delete_button);

        //First we call this
        getAndSetIntentData();

        //Set actionbar title after getAndSetIntentData method
        ActionBar ab = getSupportActionBar();
        if (ab != null) {
            ab.setTitle(last_n);
        }

        update_button.setOnClickListener(view -> {
            //And only then we call this
            MyDatabaseHelper myDB = new MyDatabaseHelper(UpdateActivity.this);
            last_n = last_name.getText().toString().trim();
            first_n = first_name.getText().toString().trim();
            middle_n = middle_name.getText().toString().trim();
            res_add = res_address.getText().toString().trim();
            years_resident = years_residency.getText().toString().trim();
            owner = ownership.getText().toString().trim();
            gender = sex.getText().toString().trim();
            citizen = citizenship.getText().toString().trim();
            tin = tinNumber.getText().toString().trim();
            cP = cellphone.getText().toString().trim();
            passport_n = passport_num.getText().toString().trim();
            place_issued = place_issue.getText().toString().trim();
            date_issued = date_issue.getText().toString().trim();
            email_add = email.getText().toString().trim();
            benefit = beneficiary.getText().toString().trim();
            dependent = dependents.getText().toString().trim();
            company_n = company_name.getText().toString().trim();
            office_number = office_num.getText().toString().trim();
            company_add = company_address.getText().toString().trim();
            company_em = company_email.getText().toString().trim();
            employment_stat = employment_status.getText().toString().trim();

            myDB.updateData(id, last_n, first_n, middle_n, res_add, years_resident,
                    owner, gender, citizen, tin, cP, passport_n, place_issued,
                    date_issued, email_add, benefit, dependent, company_n,
                    office_number, company_add, company_em, employment_stat);
        });
        delete_button.setOnClickListener(view -> {
            confirmDialog();
            recreate();
        });

    }

    void getAndSetIntentData() {
        if (getIntent().hasExtra("id") &&
                getIntent().hasExtra("last_name") &&
                getIntent().hasExtra("first_name") &&
                getIntent().hasExtra("middle_n") &&
                getIntent().hasExtra("res_add") &&
                getIntent().hasExtra("years_resident") &&
                getIntent().hasExtra("owner") &&
                getIntent().hasExtra("gender") &&
                getIntent().hasExtra("citizen") &&
                getIntent().hasExtra("tin") &&
                getIntent().hasExtra("cellphone") &&
                getIntent().hasExtra("passport_n") &&
                getIntent().hasExtra("place_issued") &&
                getIntent().hasExtra("date_issued") &&
                getIntent().hasExtra("email_add") &&
                getIntent().hasExtra("benefit") &&
                getIntent().hasExtra("dependent") &&
                getIntent().hasExtra("company_n") &&
                getIntent().hasExtra("office_number") &&
                getIntent().hasExtra("company_add") &&
                getIntent().hasExtra("company_em") &&
                getIntent().hasExtra("employment_stat")) {
            //Getting Data from Intent
            id = getIntent().getStringExtra("id");
            last_n = getIntent().getStringExtra("last_name");
            first_n = getIntent().getStringExtra("first_name");
            middle_n = getIntent().getStringExtra("middle_n");
            res_add = getIntent().getStringExtra("res_add");
            years_resident = getIntent().getStringExtra("pages");
            owner = getIntent().getStringExtra("owner");
            gender = getIntent().getStringExtra("gender");
            citizen = getIntent().getStringExtra("citizen");
            tin = getIntent().getStringExtra("tin");
            cP = getIntent().getStringExtra("cellphone");
            passport_n = getIntent().getStringExtra("passport_n");
            place_issued = getIntent().getStringExtra("place_issued");
            date_issued = getIntent().getStringExtra("date_issued");
            email_add = getIntent().getStringExtra("email_add");
            benefit = getIntent().getStringExtra("benefit");
            dependent = getIntent().getStringExtra("dependent");
            company_n = getIntent().getStringExtra("company_n");
            office_number = getIntent().getStringExtra("office_number");
            company_add = getIntent().getStringExtra("company_add");
            company_em = getIntent().getStringExtra("company_em");
            employment_stat = getIntent().getStringExtra("employment_stat");


            //Setting Intent Data
            last_name.setText(last_n);
            first_name.setText(first_n);
            middle_name.setText(middle_n);
            res_address.setText(res_add);
            years_residency.setText(years_resident);
            ownership.setText(owner);
            sex.setText(gender);
            citizenship.setText(citizen);
            tinNumber.setText(tin);
            cellphone.setText(cP);
            passport_num.setText(passport_n);
            place_issue.setText(place_issued);
            date_issue.setText(date_issued);
            email.setText(email_add);
            beneficiary.setText(benefit);
            dependents.setText(dependent);
            company_name.setText(company_n);
            office_num.setText(office_number);
            company_address.setText(company_add);
            company_email.setText(company_em);
            employment_status.setText(employment_stat);

            Log.d("stev", last_n + " " + first_n + " " + middle_n + " " +
                    res_add + " " + years_resident + " " + owner + " " +
                    gender + " " + citizen + " " + tin + " " +
                    cP + " " + passport_n + " " + place_issued + " " +
                    date_issued + " " + email_add + " " + benefit + " " +
                    dependent + " " + company_n + " " + office_number + " " +
                    company_add + " " + company_em + " " + employment_stat);
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(this, "No data.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }

    void confirmDialog() {
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        builder.setTitle("Delete " + last_n + " ?");
        builder.setMessage("Are you sure you want to delete " + last_n + " ?");
        builder.setPositiveButton("Yes", (dialogInterface, i) -> {
            MyDatabaseHelper myDB = new MyDatabaseHelper(UpdateActivity.this);
            myDB.deleteOneRow(id);
            finish();
        });
        builder.setNegativeButton("No",
                (dialogInterface, i) -> {

                });
        builder.create().show();
    }
}
````

Comment: Please use Room to save your data: https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/room?hl=vi